# The file menu of Openshot is missing. What should I do?

Tags: menu, openshot

The file menu (that would be used to export video etc.) is missing. It does not appear in the menu bar or the window title bar and it is not searchable using the HUD. The file menus appear to be fine for other applications and I have updated/upgraded packages and rebooted. What should I do to get the menu back? I want to export my video!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Export your video using shortcuts:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>  - Export project as MLT XML

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> - Export the current project as a video file

- Uninstall OpenShot completely
- Install OpenShot back

*Software Center should do.*

**Or**:

```
    sudo apt-get -s purge openshot (to see/simulate what packages will be uninstalled, I do it this way because I consider it safe)
    sudo apt-get purge openshot (if previous step is OK, remove openshot completely)
    sudo apt-get update 
    sudo apt-get install openshot
```

Comment: Please, forget the reboot thing

Comment: It will be hard in my case :D

Comment: @A.B. I've removed it from answer ;)